# MongoJS find() returning only 10 results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mongojs

i'm new to NodeJS and i'm using MongoJS to connect to my database.

All is working fine, but when i use db.collection.find() function, it returns only the first 10 results on the database.

```
function listMessages(from,to){
console.log("[REQ] User "+from+" asked chat with "+to);
var htext = 'Welcome to the chat<br/>';
db.messages2.find({$or:[{from_id: from, to_id: to}, {from_id: to, to_id: from}]},function(err, echoData) { 
  if( err || !echoData) console.log("No messages found");
  else echoData.forEach( function(returnData) {
  htext += returnData.from_id+": "+returnData.text+"<br/>";
  });
  io.sockets.emit('html message '+from, htext, to);
});
}
```

It works fine, but returns only the first 10 results on the database, even if i use limit.
I've tried to use this too, and it didnt worked:

```
db.messages2.find({$or:[{from_id: from, to_id: to}, {from_id: to, to_id: from}]},{},{limit: 50}, function(err, echoData) {
```

What I need to do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default limit in mongoDB is 10

from the documentation:

> collection.find(query[[[, fields], options], callback]);
>
> options - defines extra logic (sorting options, paging etc.)
>
> Paging
>   Paging can be achieved with option parameters limit and skip

so with a new limit:

```
db.messages2.find({}, {}, {limit: 1000}, function(err, echoData) {
```

Comment: I've tried, and it still returning only the first 10 results in the database.

Comment: are you sure you have more than 10 matching records? try removing your query conditions.

Comment: Yes, it have like 40 records. I've removed the or and put to search only for {from_id: from, to_id: to}. It worked fine, but with $or condition the error comes back.

Comment: It worked for now, i had a error in my from/to variables. Thanks.